# Normalizing nested data for React/Redux App

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalizr

I have been trying to wrap my head around normalizing nested data for my redux store with https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Upon logging in a user I get back a response with their info and relationships to other data types.

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "207",
    "type": "users",
    "attributes": {
        "email": "roberta@nitzsche.biz",
        "last-sign-in-at": null,
        "username": "april.johns",
        "first-name": "Audie",
        "last-name": "Halvorson",
        "short-bio": "Ut exercitationem ",
        "bio": "Ut exercitationem totam perferendis consequatur dolorem veritatis dolorem.",
        "location": null,
        "gender": "male",
        "birthday": "1986-10-07",
        "email-digest": "daily_digest",
        "email-notifications": "instantl_notifications",
        "auth-token": "_HV-S6qrdobecr-rr6gs",
        "avatar-large-2x": "/missing_avatar.png",
        "avatar-large": "/missing_avatar.png",
        "cover-desktop-2x": "/missing_cover.png",
        "cover-desktop": "/missing_cover.png",
        "cover-mobile-2x": "/missing_cover.png",
        "cover-mobile": "/missing_cover.png",
        "wp-id": null,
        "created-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.565Z",
        "updated-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.565Z"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "websites": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "url": "http://mohr.org/coy_rowe",
                    "user-id": 207,
                    "created-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.651Z",
                    "updated-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.651Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        "books": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Outdoors & Industrial",
                    "image-url": "https://robohash.org/sitveritatisab.png?size=300x300&set=set1",
                    "author": "Meggie Balistreri",
                    "created-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.629Z",
                    "updated-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.629Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        "movies": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Movies, Home & Electronics",
                    "image-url": "https://robohash.org/quiaarchitectoodit.png?size=300x300&set=set1",
                    "author": "Eveline Ziemann",
                    "created-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.642Z",
                    "updated-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.642Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        "interests": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "name": "Synergistic Aluminum Gloves",
                    "created-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.596Z",
                    "updated-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.596Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        "virtues": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "name": "Ergonomic Wool Gloves",
                    "created-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.582Z",
                    "updated-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.582Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        "features": {
            "data": [

            ]
        },
        "strengths": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "name": "Ergonomic Wool Gloves",
                    "created-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.582Z",
                    "updated-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.582Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        "teachers": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "name": "Ergonomic Wool Gloves",
                    "created-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.582Z",
                    "updated-at": "2016-10-07T23:16:13.582Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

After reading through a lot of tutorials I believe my data normalized would be best represented by this shape.

```
"currentUser" {
  "lastUpdated": 0,
  "userId": 207,
  "attributes": {
    "email": "roberta@nitzsche.biz",
    "last-sign-in-at": null,
    "username": "april.johns",
    "first-name": "Audie",
    "last-name": "Halvorson",
    "short-bio": "Ut exercitationem ",
    "bio": "Ut exercitationem totam perferendis consequatur",
    // etc....
  },
  "relationships": {
    "websites": [11],
    "books": [22],
    "movies": [33],
    "interests": [21],
    "virtues": [34],
    "features": [22],
    "strengths": [15],
    "teachers": [45],    
  }
}
```

Does this mean I create Schemas for all the relationship  types ?

websites
books
movies
interests
virtues
features
strengths
teachers

and then one relationshipSchema that gets defined with all those schemas nested ? For the relationship's all types will be referenced in different areas though out the site.

ex) page where they select interests and I get a response back of all interests.

```
[
    {
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Fantastic Wooden Hat",
        "created_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Fantastic Wooden Hat",
        "created_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Fantastic Wooden Hat",
        "created_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Fantastic Wooden Hat",
        "created_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z"
    }
]
```

Which I normalize too...

```
{
    54: {
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Fantastic Wooden Hat",
        "created_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z"
    },
    55: {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Fantastic Wooden Hat",
        "created_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z"
    },
    56: {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Fantastic Wooden Hat",
        "created_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z"
    },
    57: {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Fantastic Wooden Hat",
        "created_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-12T18:54:01.669Z"
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also articles, tutorials, video examples out there as well.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to flatten items that have no id. Items that have no id cannot be *referenced*.

You could add ids like you did everywhere, but note that unless you plan to reference these items from more than one place, there's no benefit to flattening the hierarchy. It only adds needless complexity.

Even if your items already have ids, there's no use in flattening the hierarchy unless you plan to reference these items by that id.

One case where you should flatten the hierarchy is when one item is used by more than one other object. Here a reference is crucial because otherwise when the item is modified in one place it could remain the same elsewhere, even if you try to prevent that, because of bugs or later code changes made by someone who didn't know there are multiple copies. This leads to diverging copies which are essentially data corruption.

Relational databases often reference items that are only referenced once because many of them do not support per-row hierarchies. This can be alleviated by using names like `address_street` and `address_city` rather than creating a separate addresses table. Making separate tables in this case is bad normalization.

Object databases on the other hand have no problem with hierarchical data in a single object.

In some cases sub objects still have ids. For instance, in Mongo DB, objects in arrays have ids. This allows the DB to recognise deletions and reordering. In React, the `key` prop exists for the exact same reason.

You can use such an id in your own code as well for the same purpose, without flattening the hierarchy.

Note that referencing items from code might possibly also constitute a reference.

For instance, if you have a component `WebSiteEditor` and you do *not* flatten the hierarchy, the component needs to know the id of the website as well as the id of the user to whom the site belongs. If you *do* flatten the hierarchy, this component would only need the id.

Ids of nested items need to only be locally unique, whereas ids of top level items need to be globally unique or at least unique per collection.

My recommendation is to not flatten items unless these items are referenced from more than one place.

Comment: thank you for explaining that, Looks like I was getting a little trigger happy with the idea of flattening my data.  After reading through your response and thinking about the problem again. It seems that I really want to focus my efforts to only flattening the `relationships` data as those relationship types will be used in multiple places.